# Algebraic closure of p-adic rationals, $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$, and its completion, $\Omega_p$, are not locally compact

Tags: real-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

Trying to show $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ and $\Omega_p$ are *not* locally compact.
I can prove it by showing that the unit sphere is *not* locally compact.
That is to say, any sequence on the unit sphere has no converging sub-sequence.

I tried to take a sequence of distinct roots of unity but I can't seem to move pass that.
Any ideas?

Comment: In order to see that these are not locally compact, it might be worth revising why $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and its _finite_ extensions are indeed locally compact.  This may help you to construct the sequence you're looking for.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I know that a these fields are locally compact iff their valuation ring is compact. the roots of unity are part of the val ring so I guess we have that any sequence has a converging sub-sequence. So if I get what you're saying, I should show that the val ring in not compact. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a field $K$ with non-archimedean valuation $v$, if $K$ is locally compact, then $K$ is complete.  To prove this, note that $K$ is locally compact iff $O_K$ is compact.  Since the topology on $O_K$ is defined by a metric, this gives $O_K$ is complete.  So $K$ is complete.  This solves $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.

For $\Omega_p$, we appeal to another consequence of locally compact: that $v$ must be a discrete valuation.  Since $O_K$ is compact, the quotient $O_K/I_a$ is compact for any $a>0$, where $I_a$ the ideal $\{v>a\}$.  But $O_K/I_a$ is discrete (since we live in an ultrametric space), so there are only finitely many points.  This shows $v(O)-\{0\}$ has a smallest element.  But of course the valuation on $\Omega_p$ is not discrete (it already fails for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$).

In fact, we have

> **Theorem** Let $K$ be a field with non-archimedean valuation $v$.  Then $K$ is locally compact iff the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $K$ is complete;
> 2. $v$ is a discrete valuation; and
> 3. the residue field $k$ is finite.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was kinda hoping for a solution using the sequence of roots of unity I mentioned, if possible.  

That being said, I don't get why "Since the topology on $O_K$ is defined by a metric, this gives $O_K$ is complete. So $K$ is complete". How did you get $O_K$ is complete by it being defined by a metric? Why $O_K$ being complete has to do with $K$ being complete?

Comment: $O_K$ is a compact metric space, so is complete (and totally bounded).  Any Cauchy sequence in $K$ eventually lives in some translate of $O_K$, so that gives $K$ complete too.

Comment: Great! that settles it for $\bar{\mathbb Q}_p$. Regarding $\Omega_p$, I'm sorry, I really tried but I can't seem to understand your answer. I don't wanna nag, but do you have a different way of addressing this problem?

Comment: Instead of using roots of unity, let's try: how many copies of $pO_K$ are there in $O_K$?  If there are infinitely many, then we are done because we can make a sequence hop around these copies.  Note that $pO_K\subset \sqrt{p}O_K\subset p^{1/4}O_K\subset\dots$ is an infinite chain of strictly increasing closed subgroup of $O_K$.  So there must be (uncountably) infinitely many copies of $pO_K$ inside $O_K$.  This works for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $\Omega_p$.

Comment: So we have a sequence in $O_K$ that has no convergent subsequence.  So $K$ is not locally compact.

Comment: Thanks for the patience :)